# Function which returns connection variable

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

In my Java application I have such code:

```
private static OracleDataSource oracleDatasource;

public static OracleConnection getConnection() throws SQLException 
{
    final OracleConnection conn = (OracleConnection) oracleDatasource.getConnection("user", "password");
    return conn;
}
```

I would like to write equivalent of such function in Postgres JDBC. I know that I could use this line

```
private static PGSimpleDataSource postgresDatasource;
```

to define data source. But how can I define and return connection variable like it was in Oracle?

Comment: That would look pretty much the same in Postgres except for PGConnection rather than OracleConnection. But it would be better to work with `java.sql.Connection` instead

Comment: Oh, okey. Thanks.